# File Upload Tools for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, file-upload

Can anyone suggest tools which can upload a variety of files (csv, xls, etc.) to SQL Server?

I can create similar tools in .net but want to save time on it and would rather buy a tool which can validate the file for the correct data types, required columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look into SSIS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx  It seems to be the standard etl tool in sql server environments.

Comment: I am looking for a tool which end users can use. It has to be as simple a possible.